# What is proper username in Cognito User Pool?

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I need to check that a proper username is entered in the custom signin form on my web site to pass it to Auth.signUp method of aws-amplify.

Things like minimum/maximum number of characters and allowed characters.

Documentation at [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html#user-pool-settings-username-email-phone-attributes) does not help, please point me to a correct page, thank you!

Comment: [Adding user pool password requirements](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-policies.html), [The username must be unique within a user pool. A username can be reused, but only after you delete it and it is no longer in use](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html#:~:text=The%20username%20must%20be%20unique%20within%20a%20user%20pool.%20A%20username%20can%20be%20reused%2C%20but%20only%20after%20you%20delete%20it%20and%20it%20is%20no%20longer%20in%20use.)

Comment: Thanks @Luuk, but it does not say anything about min/max length and allowed characters. Does it mean there are no such limitations?

Comment: apparently, because otherwise it should have been mentioned in that docs

Comment: @Luuk, it didn't accept "&^   @`` `` " username :)

Comment: Blame/Inform the owners by using the `feedback` button on the top right of their website ?

Comment: Done that.. Still strange that after all the decades there is no such information. Nobody ever checked that username is correct before sending it to Cognito?

Comment: I am not able to check for correctness, when I do not know the rules that apply to that. Maybe `abcdefg` is a correct username, but you might have a rule that you cannot have consecutive letters is your username, which makes this an invalid username (to you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See AWS SDK for validation rules.

> The username for the user. Must be unique within the user pool. **Must
> be a UTF-8 string between 1 and 128 characters**. After the user is
> created, the username can't be changed.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/interfaces/admincreateusercommandinput.html

Not perhaps a perfect description but has at least the minimum and maximum character count.

Edit: Cognito API reference reveals that regex pattern for username validation is: **[\p{L}\p{M}\p{S}\p{N}\p{P}]+**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminCreateUser.html

BTW, username cannot be changed after creation so perhaps you want to use preferred_username attribute to store the username which a user submits in sign in form (and make back-end to generate a value for username automatically (uuid for example)).

The document behind the link states:

> Activate the preferred_username attribute so that your user can change the user name that they use to sign in while their username attribute value doesn't change.

Comment: Can you provide a link where [\p{L}\p{M}\p{S}\p{N}\p{P}]+ comes from?

Comment: Sure. I try to find it. Forget to save the link and was not able to provide it in my answer.

Comment: @eugenekr See my edited answer. Was not able to find easily the SDK document but it is also mentioned in the Cognito API reference.